# How can I show multiple meta-boxes with various numbers in each post?

Tags: php, wordpress

My custom `post-type` will have various number custom meta-boxes (a `div` with multiple fields) in each post:

```
$metaBox = '<div class="inside">
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="' . $title . '">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Type</label>
         <input type="text" name="type" value="' . $type . '">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea name="text">' . $text . '</textarea>
        </div>
</div>';
```

Below are the value variables:

```
//Title
$title = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_title', true);

// Type
$type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_type', true);

// Text
$text = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_text', true);
```

Saving them using the below function:

```
// SAVE FIELDS DATA
function save_meta_box_data($post_id) {
// verify taxonomies meta box nonce
if (!isset($_POST['meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    return;
}

// return if autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return;
}

// Check the user's permissions.
if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
    return;
}

// store custom fields values
// Title
if (isset($_REQUEST['title'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_title', sanitize_text_field($_POST['title']));
}

// Type
if (isset($_REQUEST['type'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_type', sanitize_text_field($_POST['type']));
}

// Text
if (isset($_REQUEST['text'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_text', sanitize_text_field($_POST['text']));
}}

add_action('save_post', 'save_meta_box_data');
```

As various posts will have different number of Metaboxes, with below code I want to count `$metaBox` and display with `foreach`.

```
<div class="wrap">
   <?php
    if (isset($metaBox) && is_array($metaBox)) {
        $i = 1;
        $metaBox = '';

        foreach ($metaBox as $box) {
            echo '$metaBox';
        }
    }
    echo $metaBox;
    $i++;
    ?>
</div>
```

With the above, displaying only the last saved `$metaBox`, not all the saved.
How can I get all the various numbers of `$metaBox` in a post?

Comment: If you have multiple boxes, you should add [ ] to the name of each input, which will produce an array. Otherwise you only will get the last box on a save.

Comment: @rebru, adding `[]` to `name` did not worked; I want to get the entire multiple  `$metaBox`es.

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo $metaBox;` instruction is outside the loop. Inside the loop, the instruction `echo '$metaBox';` will display the string *$metaBox*, not the content.

Remove the single quotes around `'$metaBox'` inside the loop. Discard your `$i` variable which is useless.

Comment: `<div class="wrap">
   <?php
    if (isset($metaBox) && is_array($metaBox)) {
        $i = 1;
        $metaBox = '';

        foreach ($metaBox as $box) {
            echo $box;
        }
    } else {
    echo $metaBox;
    $i++;
    ?>
</div>`  Did this changes, not worked.